# Runtime Error 3061 too few parameters expected 1 DAO declarations

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, dao

I have been looking for some code that creates a calendar year and will take data from a table and place it in the corresponding date on the calendar.  I found some code online (from an older version of access) that pretty much fit the bill, with some modifications it does exactly what I need it to do.  Originally, the code pulled data from one table and it was set up to run on the current year.  I use two queries, qr_SafetyCal and qr_SafetyCal2, to refine data from the one table. The first query prioritizes the data and eliminates multiple events on any given day.  The second query uses the results from the first and specifies the year in the query criteria.

The code works flawlessly as long as I set the year criteria in the qr_SafetyCal2 and specify the first day, ex. 1/1/2017 (datStart) in the underlying code of the calendar year I want displayed.

After getting the code squared away I created a pop up form the user to select the year for the report but when I run the report I get the following error, Runtime Error 3061 too few parameters expected 1.

From what I have been able to research, I believe I changed the dynamic of the code when I referenced the form in the query criteria that the DAO Recordset Used. 
As I understand it, the criteria in the query is not passed to the rs and therefore needs to be declared in the code.  What I can't figure out is how to declare the variables in the code through reference to the form.  I hope that makes some sense to somebody, long explanation but hard to describe something you don't understand.

Below is all the code and you will see some things I've rem'd out that I have tried but did not work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. I apologize ahead of time if the code is not formatted correctly.

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private m_strCTLLabel  As String
Private m_strCTLLabelHeader As String
Private colCalendarDates As Collection

Function getCalendarData() As Boolean
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strDate As String
Dim strCode As String

Dim i As Integer

    'Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    'Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDef("qr_SafetyCal2")
    'qdf.Parameters("[Forms]![fr_SafetyCal]![cboYear]") = [Forms]![fr_SafetyCal]![cboYear]
    'Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset("qr_SafetyCal2", dbOpenDynaset)

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qr_SafetyCal2", dbOpenDynaset)

    Set colCalendarDates = New Collection
    With rs
        If (Not .BOF) Or (Not .EOF) Then
            .MoveLast
            .MoveFirst
        End If
        If .RecordCount > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To .RecordCount
                strDate = .Fields("Date")
                strCode = .Fields("ShortName")
                colCalendarDates.Add strCode, strDate
                .MoveNext
            Next i
        End If
        .Close
    End With
    'Return of dates and data collection form qr_SafetyCal2
    Set rs = Nothing

End Function

Public Sub loadReportYearCalendar(theReport As Report)
Dim i As Integer
Dim datStart As Date
Dim rptControl As Report

    m_strCTLLabel = "labelCELL"
    m_strCTLLabelHeader = "labelDAY"

    'Load calendar data for the specified year into the collection
    Call getCalendarData

    With theReport
        'Get the first month of the specified year
        datStart = "1/1/2017" '"1/1/" & Year(Date), "1/1/" & Forms!
        [fr_SafetyCal]![cboYear], Forms![fr_SafetyCal]![txtCalYear]
        'Add the specified year to the report's label
        .Controls("labelCalendarHeaderLine2").Caption = Year(datStart) & " 
        iCalendar"
        For i = 1 To 12
            'Set pointer to subreport control hosting the mini-calendar
            Set rptControl = .Controls("childCalendarMonth" & i).Report
            'Run procedure to populate control with it's respective year
            Call loadReportCalendar(rptControl, datStart)
            'Reset and obtain first day of the following month
            datStart = DateAdd("m", 1, datStart)
        Next i
     End With
    'Clean up
    Set colCalendarDates = Nothing
    Set rptControl = Nothing
End Sub


Public Sub loadReportCalendar(theReport As Report, Optional StartDate As 
Date, Optional theHeaderColor As Variant)
Dim i As Integer
Dim intCalDay As Integer
Dim datStartDate As Date
Dim intWeekDay As Integer

    datStartDate = StartDate
    intWeekDay = Weekday(datStartDate)

    With theReport

        .Controls("labelMONTH").Caption = Format(StartDate, "mmmm")

        'Change the day label's backcolor if necessary
        If Not (IsMissing(theHeaderColor)) Then
             For i = 1 To 7
                 .Controls("labelDayHeader" & i).BackColor = theHeaderColor
            Next
        End If

        For i = 1 To 42
            With .Controls(m_strCTLLabel & i)
                If (i >= intWeekDay) And (Month(StartDate) = 
                Month(datStartDate)) Then
                    If (datStartDate = Date) Then
                        .BackColor = 14277081
                    End If

                    On Error Resume Next

                    Dim strCaption As String
                    Dim strKey As String

                    strKey = datStartDate
                    strCaption = ""
                    strCaption = colCalendarDates.Item(strKey)
                    colCalendarDates.Remove strKey
                    'Set back color to grean on days in the past that have 
                    no corresponding event
                    If (datStartDate < Date) And (strCaption = vbNullString) Then
                    .Caption = Day(datStartDate)
                    .Bold = False
                    .BackColor = vbGreen
                    .ForeColor = vbWhite
                    .Heavy = True
                'Do not set a back color for days in the future
                ElseIf (datStartDate > Date) And (strCaption = vbNullString) Then
                    .Caption = Day(datStartDate)
                    .Bold = False
                'Set the corresponding labels and formats for each specified event
                Else
                    .Caption = strCaption
                    .Bold = True
                    Select Case strCaption
                        Case "FA"
                            .BackColor = vbYellow
                            .ForeColor = 0
                            .LeftMargin = 0
                            .TextAlign = 2
                        Case "FAM"
                            .BackColor = vbYellow
                            .ForeColor = 0
                            .LeftMargin = 0
                            .TextAlign = 2
                            .Heavy = True
                        Case "LTA"
                            .BackColor = vbRed
                            .ForeColor = vbWhite
                            .LeftMargin = 0
                            .TextAlign = 2
                        Case "MED"
                            .BackColor = vbRed
                            .ForeColor = vbWhite
                            .LeftMargin = 0
                            .TextAlign = 2
                    End Select

                End If

               datStartDate = DateAdd("d", 1, datStartDate)
            Else
                .Caption = ""
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Here is SQL for the two queries, the first is qr_SafetyCal and the second is qr_SafetyCal2:

```
SELECT tb_CaseLog.Date, Max(tb_Treatment.Priority) AS MaxOfPriority, 
Count(tb_Treatment.TreatmentID) AS CountOfTreatmentID
FROM tb_Treatment INNER JOIN tb_CaseLog ON tb_Treatment.TreatmentID = 
tb_CaseLog.Treatment
GROUP BY tb_CaseLog.Date;

SELECT qr_SafetyCal.Date, tb_Treatment.ShortName, 
qr_SafetyCal.CountOfTreatmentID AS [Count], Year([Date]) AS CalYear
FROM qr_SafetyCal INNER JOIN tb_Treatment ON qr_SafetyCal.MaxOfPriority = 
tb_Treatment.Priority;
```

Comment: Probably won't make any difference but because the Function does not return a value to the calling procedure, it could just be a Sub.

Comment: Code to set datStart should not even compile. Do you run Debug>Compile after code edits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to reference QueryDef.

Open the recordset object with filtered dataset by referencing the combobox like:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM qr_SafetyCal2 WHERE CalYear=" & [Forms]![fr_SafetyCal]![cboYear], dbOpenDynaset)
```

or if the code is behind the form:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM qr_SafetyCal2 WHERE CalYear=" & Me.[cboYear], dbOpenDynaset)
```

Both examples assume the field is a number type.

If there is no field in query with the year value, it can be extracted from date value field in the VBA construct:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM qr_SafetyCal2 WHERE Year([YourFieldnameHere])=" & [Forms]![fr_SafetyCal]![cboYear], dbOpenDynaset)
```

Code for setting datStart variable:

```
'Get the first month of the specified year
datStart = "1/1/" & Forms![fr_SafetyCal].[cboYear]
```

Comment: It is still stopping at this point.  I am afraid I did not pin-point the actual failure in my description and that would have been helpful.  There is a reference in Public Sub loadReportYearCalendar that builds the calendar based on the first day of the year, referenced in the code as datStart. In the example it is 1/1/2017 and you can see my attempts at referencing the form.  Anytime I time I try to reference the form I get the Run time Error 3061.  I'm not sure what YourFieldnameHere references and what do I need to with the datStart reference in the Public Sub

Comment: YourFieldnameHere must be replaced with name of field from query that has the Year value. Suggested syntax is correct for opening filtered recordset (I did edit answer for a couple of typos). If qr_SafetyCal2 does nothing but filter qr_SafetyCal by the year then perhaps you should reference qr_SafetyCal instead. You did not provide query statements for review. Apparently have several issues within code and probably should be separate questions to deal with each one at a time. Get the function running properly first. Call it from the VBA Immediate window to test it independently of the Sub.

Comment: Tried checking the datStart variable in the immediate window and returned nothing.  I think you are getting the jest of my question but I am not sure how to get the function running properly first.

Comment: Hopefully seeing the queries will help.  I think I mentioned above, if I did I apologize but if I place 2017 in the query field CalYear of the second query, qr_SafetyCal2 and then assign "1/1/2017" to the datStart varibale in the code, it works great!  However, when I reference the the form cboYear, dop down box containing the year value in the qr_SafetyCal2 and reference the following in the Public Sub LoadReportYearCalendar datStart = "1/1/" & Forms![fr_SafetyCal]![cboYear]... it crashes

Comment: Calling getCalendarData() function from Immediate window has nothing to do with the datStart variable.

Comment: Note indicates the edit is under peer review and I guess will be visible once its approved

Comment: I added it to the original post

Comment: In answer to the immediate window response, I'm not sure what you are referring to as getting the function running properly first.

Comment: So the function opens the recordset object and doesn't error. Get that working then look at setting the datStart variable. Include a `Debug.Print rs!(ShortName)` line in the loop and value will show in immediate if the recordset opens properly.

Comment: I honestly thought I was getting the function to operate correctly by testing its operation before I tried to call the variables from the form.  I appreciate your patients.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got no result so I set all the perimeters back to the original state and tested it's operation, it worked, then inserted Debug.Print rs!(Short Name) in the code just under where the rs is called and got "Compile Error: Variable not defined" with Short Name highlighted in blue.  I am not doing something right!

Comment: The Debug goes inside the loop. Did you type a space in `Short Name`? Sorry, no parens. Two versions: `rs!ShortName` or `rs.Fields("ShortName")`. Only you can drop the `rs` because of the `With`.

Comment: I meant inside the `For` loop.

Comment: June7 I have created a separate functional database with all component pieces so you can see everything... very small but I am not sure how I can get it to you.  Suggestion?

Comment: Upload to a fileshare site such as Box.com and post a link to the file. Or use a forum that allows attaching files to posts.

Comment: The file is uploaded to my Google Drive at the following link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N8eiz8sMy0RREgeRY3FQVwS5O8WeK82q/view?usp=sharing

Double click iCalendar12 to see the result.

Comment: OK, have to concatenate reference to the combobox. I thought the SQL could evaluate the full form/control reference syntax within quote marks but apparently not. See edit to my answer. Then fix the code for building the date. I don't get an error message but the report won't open unless I delete month 12 and change code to cycle only 11 times. But then I see only 9 months on each page and the report is 322 pages. This question has its answer. Time to go back to drawing board and a new question.

Comment: Okay, bizarre, don't know what I did but now getting all 12 months. Works great!

Comment: SUCCESS, it worked!  I tested each year, initiated from the input form and worked flawlessly.  I have marked the question as answered but I can't figure out how rate your input.  Thank You for your help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer approval. Rate a post with up/down vote.